# How to update innerHTML without modifying the entire content?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a javascript **(AJAX)** that periodically makes an `XMLHttpRequest` to get some data from a PHP file and *append* the returned data to the `innerHTML` of a <p> tag. However, every time the new content gets added to the block, the entire content of the paragraph seems to reload: *when I select some text, the selection disappears when the data is updated*.

Here's the code:

```
<script>

    function requestChange(){
        setInterval(updateData, 2000);
    }

    function updateData(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "content_provider.php";
        req.open("POST", url, true);
        req.send();

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                var data = req.responseText;

                //updating the innerHTML content
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += data;
            }
        };
    }

</script>

<body onload="requestChange()">
        <p id="data"></p>
</body>
```

### How do I make the change in the innerHTML *static*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately using innerHTML will always destroy the previous content, if you are using jQuery you can instead use the append method, you haven't mentioned jQuery, so I'll assume that you're not using it.

You can instead use insertAdjacentHTML() instead of innerHTML, this method requires you to pass one of the positions below as the first argument and then the text you wish to add.

```
'beforebegin' // Before the element itself.
'afterbegin' // Just inside the element, before its first child.
'beforeend'  //Just inside the element, after its last child.
'afterend'  //After the element itself.
```

In  your case here's how it would look:

```
document.getElementById('data').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html_to_insert);
```

Comment: I could make use of `jQuery` too! :-)

Comment: @fethe beat me to it

Comment: Using the `'afterend'` parameter is putting the new content in the beginning :-/

Comment: if using jQuery, you can simply use the append method like so: 

    $( "#data" ).append( data );

Comment: doesn't 'beforeend' do what you expect?

using 'afterend' will put the data outside of the div that you're trying to append to.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

It's what you need in this case because `insertAdjacentHTML`  inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position (first parameter), but does not reparse the hole tree.

```
document.getElementById('data').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data);
```

Comment: FYI, link is dead.

Comment: Someone unupvoted for this answer. But you deserve for this. +1 But you need to use beforeend

Comment: @BhojendraNepal The code **does not** produce the desired output: the parameter should have been `'beforeend'` instead of `'afterend'`.

Comment: that's correct,  my bad. `afterend` adds a sibling to the elemeny. Modified

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it but I think, this will work if you append a new container everytime you receive a new response:

```
    function requestChange(){
        setInterval(updateData, 2000);
    }

    function updateData(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "content_provider.php";
        req.open("POST", url, true);
        req.send();

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                var data = req.responseText;
                var newInfoBox = document.createElement('SPAN');
                newInfoBox.innerHTML = data;
                //updating the innerHTML content
                document.getElementById('data').appendChild(newInfoBox);
            }
        };
    }

</script>

<body onload="requestChange()">
        <p id="data"></p>
</body>
```